# Enviar ubicacion/coordenadas a bd MySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, script

Luego de buscar por todos lados no logre encontrar una respuesta concreta, intente hacerlo como lo hizo alguien aquí en el foro y nada..

No soy un experto ni se mucho, por eso también se me complica. Necesito que al enviar un form se envíen las coordenadas desde donde se envió el form hasta mi base de datos. (Latitud y longitud) Obviamente pidiendo permiso.

Dejo un poco como es el código así me dan una mano..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vivorata Zona 3</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
      <h1>Vivorata Zona 3</h1>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Mensaje">
      <input type="submit" name="register">
    </form>
    <?php
      include("vivorataz3reg.php");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

--

```
<?php

include("con_db3.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
  if (strlen($_POST['name']) >=1 && strlen($_POST['message']) >=0) {
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO VivorataZ3(nombre, mensaje, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$fecha')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);
    if ($resultado) {
      ?>
      <h3 class="ok">¡Enviado!</h3>
      <?php
    } else {
      ?>
      <h3 class="bad">¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
      <?php
      }
    } else {
      ?>
      <h3 class="bad">¡Completa los campos!</h3>
      <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Y encontré este que no esta nada mal.. Pero seguro haré c*gadas si lo pongo sin entenderlo del todo o agregar las cosas que faltan para que funcione bien.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    alert("¡Permitenos saber tu ubicación!");
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mostrarUbicacion);
                    } else {alert("¡Error! Este navegador no soporta la Geolocalización.");}
                
                    function mostrarUbicacion(position) {
                    var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
                    var div = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
                    div.innerHTML = "Ubicación actual:" + latitud + "&nbsp;" + longitud;}   
                    
                    function refrescarUbicacion() { 
                    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(mostrarUbicacion);} 
                </script>
```

Lo que necesito es que al ingresar a la pagina, el navegador pida permiso para saber la ubicacion, llenar el form y al enviarlo que me lleguen junto a los datos del form, su ubicacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar la [API de geolocalización](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) { console.log(pos); });`

Añade un campo oculto en el formulario:

```html
  <input type="hidden" id="coords" name="coords" value="">
```

Añade este código Javascript:

```javascript
  function pos_ok (posicion) {
    console.log(posicion);
    var latitud  = posicion.coords.latitude;
    var longitud = posicion.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('coords').value = latitud + ',' + longitud;
  }

  function pos_fallo () {
    console.log('Error al geolocalizar.');
  }

  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log('Geolocalización no disponible.');
  } else {
    console.log('Geolocalizando...');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos_ok, pos_fallo);
  }
```